# Best way to export records with attachments

Tags: attachment, data-export

I'm specifically trying to do this with cases. We have a script written internally to handle this but I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way.

Comment: An ETL tool like Talend would be better than writing scripts, If frequency  is like Weekly or monthly you can use standard SF Weekly Export to get that data weekly for free

Comment: so you are saying that I can export objects and their associated attachments with SF Weekly Export. Definitely not paying for something since this is a one and done situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce Standard Weekly export is the best way if you want it weekly or monthly without paying for extra ETL tools or API calls in a process to do so....

Best part, it backups files, Attachments and Documents, all in Zipped CSV which can be easily downloaded.

[image]

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_exportdata.htm&type=5